# Sendgrid locally works, but on production don't (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, sendgrid, email

I have weird issue, locally on my windows machine everything works fine, but when i deploy my app on hosting from some reason i get internal server error in this function, i dont see any details or any message what is wrong, so i am a bit confused how i should handle this and how i can debug this, anyone had similar issues ?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require_once("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

function sendRegistrationEmail($object) {
    $message = file_get_contents('email/templates/RegistrationTemplate.html');

    $message = str_replace('%firstName%', $object['firstName'], $message);
    $message = str_replace('%lastName%', $object['lastName'], $message);
    $message = str_replace('%email%', $object['email'], $message);
    $message = str_replace('%password%', $object['passwordHash'], $message);
    //var_dump works here, but
    $from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "jane.doe@gmail.com");
    //on this line it does not enter.
    $subject = "Leben IN WÜRDE Account Created";
    $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, 'jon.doe@gmail.com');
    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", $message);
    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    $apiKey = 'myKey';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    echo $response->statusCode();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do the requires work on the server? The easiest way to check this is to check your php error log - if the requires are missing, it will give you an explicit error.

Comment: Yes requires work, i used file_exist method to check it out and i get true as result, so it sees that file.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your error log (on the server)? Nothing is jumping out as wrong and I'm hoping that your logs will have some more info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the PHP version on your server (php -v). To my best understanding, the namespace feature was added in PHP 5.3. Since the script break at the line where it first uses the name space feature ($from = new SendGrid\Email), that's what I think.

Comment: Did that and its 5.6 php version.